# FCM Notification On Android Not Opening Chrome When Tapped

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am developing a website for a company. I need to send a notification from the server to all `supervisors` accounts (whether on browser or mobile). So I implement the `FCM` for sending the notification.

In the client web page I have these code to make the client subscribe to `FCM`:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging
    .requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');

        // get the token in the form of promise
        return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(async function (token) {
        console.log('Token: ' + token);
        await fetch("/api/Supervisor/SubscribeToAllTopic?token=" + token);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });

let enableForegroundNotification = true;
messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);

    if (enableForegroundNotification) {
        let notification = payload.notification;

        const notificationOptions = {
            body: notification.body,
            data: payload.data
        };

        navigator.serviceWorker
            .getRegistrations()
            .then((registration) => {
                //registration[0].showNotification(notification.title);
                registration[0].showNotification(notification.title, notificationOptions);
            });
    }
});
```

Then there is service worker `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to handle the background activities:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-messaging.js",
);
// For an optimal experience using Cloud Messaging, also add the Firebase SDK for Analytics.
importScripts(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js",
);

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    appId: "xxxx"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log(
        "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
        payload,
    );
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        data: payload.data
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions,
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.notification.close();
    //var urlToRedirect = event.notification.data.action;
    //event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(urlToRedirect));

    let url = event.notification.data.action;
    event.notification.close(); // Android needs explicit close.
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(windowClients => {
            // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                // If so, just focus it.
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );


});
```

The notifications are successfully sent to web browsers or mobile phones. The problem is when I tapped the notification, it was supposed to open chrome and redirect me to the `action url`. This only works if only there is an open web browser with the same `host url`.

For example, if my website is `https://mywebsite.com`, if the mobile phone is now browsing at that URL, it will open a new window and redirect to the `action url` (it works fine). If I do not have the host URL opened, then tapping the notification will do nothing, also if the mobile phone does not have a chrome instance running, tapping the notification will do nothing.

How can I always instruct the client to open chrome and redirect them to the `action url`?